# Axios -nestjs causes REFUSED, even after catching error, and NestJS app crashes

Tags: node.js, error-handling, axios, nestjs, econnrefused

My code 1:

```
import { HttpService } from '@nestjs/axios';

const res = await this.httpService
      .post(url, formData, { headers: { ...formData.getHeaders() } })
      .pipe(
        mergeMap((value) => {
          return of(value);
        }),
        catchError((error) => {
          console.log('Error Axios:', error.response.data);
          return of(error);
        }),
      );
    const data = await lastValueFrom(res);
```

My code 2:

```
 const response = await this.httpService
      .post(url, formData, {
        headers: { ...formData.getHeaders() },
      })
      .toPromise()
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
```

In both cases i got the error inside catch handle, but in both cases my app crashes e got ECONNREFUSED,if i try request again. I have to restart the application.

I have no clue to solve this. Has anyone ever had this error ?